# converting one topic to another (front_cam/camera/image to sensor_msgs/image)

Tags: ros, libviso2, hector-quadrotor, sensor-msgs#image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am thinking of incorporating visual odometry onto hector-quadrotor which currently uses LIDAR. There is a front cam functionality ( topics like:

```
/front_cam/camera/image
/front_cam/camera/image/compressed
/front_cam/camera/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/front_cam/camera/image/compressed/parameter_updates
/front_cam/camera/image/compressedDepth
/front_cam/camera/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/front_cam/camera/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/front_cam/camera/image/theora
/front_cam/camera/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/front_cam/camera/image/theora/parameter_updates
```

while the visual odometry (viso2_ros subscribes to sensor_msgs/image).

Is it possible to covert from front_cam/camera/image to sensor_msgs/image .
Tried to look up for /front_cam but couldn't find any documentation relating to that

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211794/converting-one-topic-to-another-(front_cam/camera/image-to-sensor_msgs/image)/) by [creative_cimmons](https://answers.ros.org/users/22559/creative_cimmons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [viso2_ros wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros), the input topic name for the monocular node is `image`.

You can change the input topic name using [remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments).

Try something like

```
rosrun viso2_ros mono_odometer image:=/front_cam/camera/image
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3